# Error creating bean; Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a central library for certain functions and now I have trouble integrating that library.
The library is written in spring boot and contains a class: com.common.Security.
It is defined like this:

```
package com.common;
....
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Security {
....
}
```

I try to use this in another class:

```
package org.special;
import com.common.Security;
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

@Autowired
private Security security;
....
}
```

But I get some errors:

```
Error creating bean with name 'myController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'WebServiceclient'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'webserviceClient': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'webServiceTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/special/WebServiceConfig.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate]: Factory method 'webServiceTemplate' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.Security': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; 
consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found:
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What is this `Security` type meant to do? Why is it request scoped? Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: The error is that Scope is request, but WebServiceConfig is not request scoped. If Security works without a request then you can simply change the scope. If on the other hand Security requires a request then you can't use it directly from WebServiceConfig.

Comment: It does not require a scope. It gets executed when the Application starts an the WebServiceTemplates are build.

Comment: Since your `Security` class is located in `com.common` it is not automatically picked up from your application contained in `org.special`… you'd need to add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.common")`. It'd be probably better to turn your library into a [custom starter module](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter) however.

Comment: I don't understand. Just get rid of the scope then.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Scope was quite helpfull.
I tried this before but some of my tests failed after that. I didn't see, that this was because of missing settings in application.yaml for the tests.
They were not neccessary when scope is request.